# How in tableview to set all cells to specific size and only resize the cells which receive greater length of input

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, cell

By using this code

```
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 43
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I can make cells to resize based on input. The problem is, that all the empty prototype cells are generated based on the most recent input also. Which results in all the prototype cells resizing every time when input requires more or less lines than previous input. Like [this](http://s18.postimg.org/ia3bwi1yx/Screen_Shot_2016_02_23_at_8_38_43_PM.png) and [this](http://s10.postimg.org/63fhmvbp5/Screen_Shot_2016_02_23_at_8_39_12_PM.png).

How would it be possible to set all the prototype cells to a specific height and then only resize the new cell based on the input?

Answer (score 0):

Set `textLabel.numberOfLines = 0` for your label in the cell.

Comment: it is a textview in a cell.

Comment: Do you need them to be editable, otherwise I'd recommend to use a `UILabel`. If not, you should look into `Autolayout` to make the cell height dynamic based on the size of the `UITextView`

Answer (score 0):

Implement UITableViewDelegate method heightforrowatindexpath and calculate height for cell and return.